# Why can I not create an instance of inner class?

Tags: java, class

I learnt about JAVA basic level. Then, I meet some problem... the inner class instance is not created.

```
public class example {
    class book {

        private String name = null;
        private int page = 0;

        book(String name, int page) {
            this.name = name;
            this.page = page;
        }

        String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        int getPage() {
            return this.page;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        book b1 = new book("book1", 300);       // this line is making an error
        System.out.println(b1.getName());
        System.out.println(b1.getPage());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: better yet, don't have that book class in an example class (which you 're not using anyway)

Comment: Please watch the naming conventions. Class names should start with an uppercase character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `book` class is an inner class of your `example` class, which means it requires an enclosing `example` class instance in order to be instantiated (`new example().new book("book1", 300)`).

However, it would make more sense to make the `book` class not-nested:

```
class book {
    private String name = null;
    private int page = 0;

    book(String name, int page) {
        this.name = name;
        this.page = page;
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    int getPage() {
        return this.page;
    } 
}

public class example {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        book b1 = new book("book1", 300);
        System.out.println(b1.getName());
        System.out.println(b1.getPage());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Otherwise, make the `book` class `static`